# How to use an existing object for data in a multi bar graph?

Tags: javascript, object, web, d3.js, nvd3.js

[image]
I am using the nvd3 library to make a bar graph, and I'm running into some trouble trying to figure out how to use my object properly. If I try and use the object that I created from a JSON file, the graph doesn't behave properly(see the picture that I've provided. the bars are off center). I'm building off of a multi-bar graph example so my guess is that it's still trying to display the graph as if there would be multiple bars for each x value.

```
function dataFactory(seriesNum, perSeries) {
return new d3.range(0,seriesNum).map(function(d,i) { return { //will return the amount of streams to be seen on the graph
key: 'Stream ' + i,
values: new d3.range(0,perSeries).map( function(f,j) {
  return { 
           y: 10 + Math.random()*100, // a random value is given to y and the range of 0-perSeries is put into j
           x: j
         }
})
};  
});

}
```

However, using the above function and calling it to be used for data works properly. Does anyone know what I have to do to get my object to behave like the object that comes from this function?

My json file if you need to see it:

```
{
"Member1": {
    "key":"test10",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "test10",
            "y": 20
        }
    ]
},
"Member2":{
    "key":"test9",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "test9",
            "y": 10
        }
    ]
},
"Member3":{
    "key":"test8",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "test8",
            "y": 4
        }
    ]
},
"Member4":{
    "key":"test7",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "test7",
            "y": 12
        }
    ]
},
"Member5":{
    "key":"test6",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "test6",
            "y": 30
        }
    ]
},
"Member6":{
    "key":"test5",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "test5",
            "y": 8
        }
    ]
}
,
"Member7":{
    "key":"test4",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "test4",
            "y": 27
        }
    ]
},
"Member8":{
    "key":"test3",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "test3",
            "y": 17
        }
    ]
},
"Member9":{
    "key":"test2",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "test2",
            "y": 2
        }
    ]
},
"Member10":{
    "key":"test11",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "test11",
            "y": 53
        }
    ]
},
"Member11":{
    "key":"test13",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "test13",
            "y": 55
        }
    ]
},
"Member12":{
    "key":"test14",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "test14",
            "y": 104
        }
    ]
},
"Member13":{
    "key":"test15",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "test15",
            "y": 12
        }
    ]
},
"Member14":{
    "key":"test16",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "test16",
            "y": 87
        }
    ]
}

}
```

Comment: and if there's any other parts of my code you need to see let me know

Comment: It might be better to go with a different type of chart here seeing that you don't have multiple bars.

Comment: Yeah....I thought i could make it work but learning more about how it worked i realized the same.

Comment: In any case, you can log and inspect the data by doing `console.log()` on it.